# Running Solr in a cluster - high availability only

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud, freetext

I would like to run two Solr instances on different computers as a cluster.

My main interest is High availability - meaning, in case one server crashes or is down there will be always another one.

(my performances on a single instance are great. I do not need to split the data to two servers.)

Questions: 
1. What is the best practice? 
    Is it different than clustering for index splitting? Do I need Shards?
2. Do I need zoo keeper? 
3. Is it a container based configuration (different for jetty and tomcat)
4, Do I need an external NLB for that ?
5. When one computer is up after crashing. how dows it updates its index?

Answer (score 0):

You can define numShards=1 and that's it. You need a single slice replicated for that. If you want automated cluster management and hot replication - yes, you need SolrCloud mode and ZooKeeper. Speaking about load balancing, it depends on your architecture. If you are going to use SolrJ, there is a basic load balancing implementation there.
When a node initializes, it enters the recovery stage. During the recovery stage it synchronizes with the other existing replicas as well as with its own transaction log. If its index version is old, it gets a newer version from other server.